# Add a where condition inside of aggregate function

Tags: r, conditional-statements, aggregate

I have some data that look like this:

```
 head(data1[,1:5])
               eid             created class_id   min.e.event_time. lead_date
    2610966 284546 2015-03-19 11:21:17       36 2015-03-19 11:21:17      NULL
    2610972 284554 2015-03-19 12:37:19       36 2015-03-19 12:37:19      NULL
    2610973 284554 2015-03-19 12:37:19       36 2015-03-19 12:37:19      NULL
    2610975 284558 2015-03-19 14:18:43       36 2015-03-19 14:18:43      NULL
    2610976 284558 2015-03-19 14:18:43       36 2015-03-19 14:18:43      NULL
    2610977 284558 2015-03-19 14:18:43       36 2015-03-19 14:18:43      NULL
```

This is an events table and eid is a user id. Each line is an instance of that user experiencing an event.

I'd like the count of events for each user:

```
eid_email <- aggregate(data1$eid, list(data1$eid), function(x) length(x))
```

This appears to work. Great.

But I need to add a condition. I need to count events for each user, like above, only where event_time is less than lead_date.

When I type help(aggregate) the manual says there is a subset argument that I can use with aggregate(). Can I use this argument in this way?

How can I apply a conditional to my aggregate function? If that's not possible is their another way?

** STR data1 following comment **

```
 str(data1)
'data.frame':   1906721 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ eid              : int  45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 ...
 $ created          : Factor w/ 36204 levels "0000-00-00 00:00:00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ class_id         : int  36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 ...
 $ min.e.event_time.: Factor w/ 16175 levels "2013-04-15 11:17:19",..: 10025 10025 10025 10025 10025 10025 10025 10025 10025 10025 ...
 $ lead_date        : Factor w/ 11199 levels "2012-10-11 18:39:12",..: 11199 11199 11199 11199 11199 11199 11199 11199 11199 11199 ...
 $ camp             : int  98713 59020 75796 99195 76986 57986 54062 80420 55078 70800 ...
 $ event_date       : Factor w/ 695747 levels "2008-01-18 12:18:01",..: 71975 27451 45235 72491 48792 24606 20021 52261 32169 57764 ...
 $ event            : Factor w/ 3 levels "click","open",..: 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ message_name     : Factor w/ 2707 levels ""," 2015-03 CAD Promotion Update",..: 1570 2624 1970 1881 1973 1931 1919 1983 2391 2045 ...
 $ subject_lin      : Factor w/ 2043 levels ""," Christie Office Holiday Hours",..: 311 952 318 309 495 1450 520 298 1333 750 ...
```

Comment: Could you provide the `dput` for your dataframe?

Comment: this may be easier if you use `with` and subset *outside* of aggregate: `with(mtcars, aggregate(mpg, list(gear), length)); with(mtcars[mtcars$mpg < 30, ], aggregate(mpg, list(gear), length))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this: with(data1[data1$created < data1$lead_date,], aggregate(data1$eid, list(data1$eid), function(x) length(x)))
Which output a bunch of rows and then, subsequently gave the following message: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(data1$created, data1$lead_date) :
  ‘<’ not meaningful for factors. 
So it looks it it ran and then encountered an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dplyr installed, you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data1 %>%
  mutate( event_time_POSIX = as.POSIXct(min.e.event_time., 
                                        format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                        origin="1970-01-01")) %>%
  mutate( lead_time_POSIX = as.POSIXct(lead_date, 
                                       format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                       origin="1970-01-01")) %>%
  filter( event_time_POSIX < lead_time_POSIX ) %>%
  group_by(eid) %>%
  summarize( n=n() ) 

options(dplyr.width=Inf)

print(data2)
```

Comment: did I type it wrong: data1 %>%
+ filter(min.e.event_time. < lead_date) %>%
+ group_by(eid) %>%
+ summarize(n = n())
Source: local data frame [0 x 2]

Variables not shown: eid (int), n (int)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(c(10025L, 10025L, 10025L, 10025L, 10025L, 10025L,  :
  ‘<’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Looks like your lead_date column is of incorrect type. Can you show us `str(data1)`

Comment: Added. Also, correct - lead_date can be either a date or NULL. That change things?

Comment: By the way, my example assumes that records with missing lead_dates (NA) should not be counted since it cannot be established that event_time is less than lead_date.

Comment: That would be desired in this scenario

Comment: I see. The issue is that event_time and lead_date are factors and not POSIXct. I modified my code above such that it converts both of these into POSIXct first and then does the rest.

Comment: Thanks akhmed. "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"
Incidentally, what does this mean %>% ?

Comment: This error means that the datetimes columns have something in them that is not a date. I refined the code to make sure that as.POSIXct treats these entries as NA instead of throwing an error. By the way, feel free to move the discussion to chat. I am new and I don't have enough reputation to start a chat.

Comment: Thanks akhmed. It runs now. I don;t know what it's returning though. I was expecting a table like structure (data frame?) with several thousand rows. What this returned was a sample of ten results (which look correct). But nrow(data2) (the var I assigned to your snippet) is null. str(data2) is  chr [1:9] "dplyr" "data.table" "stats" "graphics" "grDevices" "utils" "datasets" "methods" "base".
Is this expected?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it now

Comment: Great! The result was probably shortened by `print` just for display purposes. This is why  `options(dplyr.width=Inf)` was needed.